# Precise Event Synchronization with Python

Tags: python

I have a multinode network of VMs spread across several machines, one management VM and 7-15 worker VMs.  I would like to run an NTP server on the management VM and have all the worker VMs synchronize with the mangament VM.

From there I plan on having a python process on each worker VM spawn a new thread at at arbitary times from one start date.  Each process will know ahead of time (ie when the process starts) when it needs to spawn a new thread.

An approach I can think of is to synchronize the machines with NTP, subtract the known waiting time from the current time and then call usleep on the difference.

Pseudo-Code

```
for ii in eventTimes:
   curTime = getCurrentTime()
   waitTime = ii - curTime
   usleep(waitTime)
   spawnEventThread()
```

There's no shared data between the threads.  The minimum time inbetween each thread being spawned is 1 second and they should be simple enough to finish whatever they're doing in that second.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you can run an NTP server on the management VM, you can hit that NTP server with pure python code to get the "master" time, and then use that as a base for offset calculations.

```
>>> import ntplib,datetime
>>> x = ntplib.NTPClient()
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.request('master server').tx_time)
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 19, 17, 59, 24, 679769)
```

If you change the `getCurrentTime()` call in your example to a function that gets the network time, you should be good to go.

Comment: your code is syntactically incorrect and ambiguous in terms of how to fix it (parentheses placement)